# Getting values of multiple same fragment(container) to activity by unique tag

Tags: android, performance, android-studio, android-fragments

Hi I am new to android i have searching this for a week, 
i have a fragment that contains

1. textview
2. editext
3. spinner
4. calender
5. image choosing

Adding and removing same fragment in an container with unique tag. in spinner there is multiple numbers that is displayed in activity dynamically, if i add or remove same fragment, the values shown in textview should change dynamically. I know to access each instance by its tag and can get the values in activity but unable to find which fragment instance have changed.

For example, if i have added same fragment four times, made change in spinner in all the four fragment, unable to identify which instance have increased or decreased and correct the total

And also unable to find whether image is added or not.

My fragment is

```
public class Service_details extends Fragment {

    private static final String IMAGE_DIRECTORY = "/demonuts";
    private int GALLERY = 1, CAMERA = 2;
    ProgressDialog pDialog;


    TextView textView_service_no, textView_datePicker, textView_amount, textView_optionalDate;
    Spinner spinner_services;
    EditText editText_dedicated, editText_intention;
    ImageView display_photo;


    HashMap<String, String> cList = new HashMap<>();
    String[] services;

    String initial_spinner_value;
    String birthday_price;
    String deathday_price;
    String rosary_price;
    String mass_price;
    String prayer_price;
    String marriageday_price;

    OnMessageReadListener messageReadListener;

    String service_value = null;
    String service_spinner_string=null;
    String person_image_string =null;
    String editText_dedicated_string=null;
    String editText_intention_string=null;
    String textView_telecast_date_string=null;
    String textView_amount_string =null;
    String total_amount_string=null;
    String tax_amount_string=null;
    String final_total_amount_string=null;


    int c;

    int count;
    String TAG = "Fragment";

    Bitmap bitmap;

    LinearLayout linearLayout10;

    public interface OnMessageReadListener {
        void onMessageRead(String message);

    }

    public Service_details() {
        // Required empty public constructor
    }

    public static Service_details newInstance(int i) {

        Service_details service_details = new Service_details();

        Bundle bundle = new Bundle();
        int c = i;
        bundle.putInt("service_count",i);
        service_details.setArguments(bundle);
        return service_details;

    }

    Calendar cal;
    public String message;

    String path;

    int temp;

    int a;

    @SuppressLint("SetTextI18n")
    @Override
    public View onCreateView(@NonNull LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                             Bundle savedInstanceState) {



        View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_service_details, container, false);


        textView_service_no = view.findViewById(R.id.service_counting);
        editText_dedicated = view.findViewById(R.id.editText_dedicated_to);
        editText_intention = view.findViewById(R.id.editText_intention);
        textView_datePicker = view.findViewById(R.id.date_picker);
        spinner_services = view.findViewById(R.id.spinner_services);
        textView_amount = view.findViewById(R.id.textview_amount);
        display_photo = view.findViewById(R.id.display_photo);
        textView_optionalDate = view.findViewById(R.id.textview_exactDate);
        cal = Calendar.getInstance();

        linearLayout10 = view.findViewById(R.id.linear10);

        ButterKnife.bind(this, view);

        getJson();

        assert getArguments() != null;
        count = getArguments().getInt("service_count");

        Log.e(TAG, "count value :  "+ count);
        textView_service_no.setText(valueOf(count));
        ++count;



        a=0;
        display_photo.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                showPictureDialog();
            }
        });

        textView_optionalDate.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                DatePickerDialog dialog = new DatePickerDialog(getActivity(), new DatePickerDialog.OnDateSetListener() {

                    @Override
                    public void onDateSet(DatePicker arg0, int arg1, int arg2, int arg3) {
                        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                        textView_optionalDate.setText(""+arg3+"/"+(arg2+1)+"/"+arg1);
                        Toast.makeText(getActivity(), ""+arg3+"/"+(arg2+1)+"/"+arg1, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                    }
                }, cal.get(Calendar.YEAR), cal.get(Calendar.MONTH), cal.get(Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH));

                dialog.show();
            }
        });

        textView_datePicker.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {

                DatePickerDialog dialog = new DatePickerDialog(getActivity(), new DatePickerDialog.OnDateSetListener() {

                    @Override
                    public void onDateSet(DatePicker arg0, int arg1, int arg2, int arg3) {
                        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                        textView_datePicker.setText(""+arg3+"/"+(arg2+1)+"/"+arg1);
                        Toast.makeText(getActivity(), ""+arg1+"/"+(arg2+1)+"/"+arg3, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                    }
                }, cal.get(Calendar.YEAR), cal.get(Calendar.MONTH), cal.get(Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH));
                cal.add(Calendar.DAY_OF_WEEK_IN_MONTH, 5);
                dialog.getDatePicker().setMinDate(cal.getTimeInMillis());
                dialog.show();
            }
        });




        services = new String[]{"Select Service","Birth Day", "Death Day", "Rosary", "Hollymass", "Prayer", "Marriage Day"};


        ArrayAdapter<String> arrayAdapter = new ArrayAdapter<>(getActivity(), android.R.layout.simple_spinner_item, services);
        arrayAdapter.setDropDownViewResource(android.R.layout.simple_dropdown_item_1line);
        spinner_services.setAdapter(arrayAdapter);


        spinner_services.setOnItemSelectedListener(new AdapterView.OnItemSelectedListener() {


            @Override
            public void onItemSelected(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long id) {

                String spin_value = parent.getItemAtPosition(position).toString();

                ((Services)getActivity()).setCurrentSpinnerItem(spin_value);

                switch (position) {
                    case 0:

                        textView_amount.setText(cList.get("empty"));
                        display_photo.setVisibility(View.GONE);
                        linearLayout10.setVisibility(View.GONE);
                        Log.e(TAG,"textView_amount (fragment name)"+ textView_amount.getTag());
                        String message_temp = textView_amount.getText().toString();


                        if(!message_temp.equals("")){
                            a = Integer.parseInt(message_temp);
                        }
                        a = a-temp;
                        message = Integer.toString(a);

                        Log.e(TAG, "message_temp: "+message_temp);


                        messageReadListener.onMessageRead(message);
                        break;
                    case 1:
                        textView_amount.setText(cList.get("birthday_price"));
                        display_photo.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
                        linearLayout10.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
                        message_temp = textView_amount.getText().toString();


                        if(!message_temp.equals("")){
                            a = Integer.parseInt(message_temp);
                        }
                        a = a-temp;
                        message = Integer.toString(a);                        

                        a= Integer.parseInt(message_temp);
                        a= a-temp;
                        message = Integer.toString(a);*/
                        messageReadListener.onMessageRead(message);
                        break;
                    case 2:
                        textView_amount.setText(cList.get("deathday_price"));
                        display_photo.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
                        linearLayout10.setVisibility(View.GONE);
                        message_temp = textView_amount.getText().toString();


                        if(!message_temp.equals("")){
                            a = Integer.parseInt(message_temp);
                        }
                        a = a-temp;
                        message = Integer.toString(a);
                        messageReadListener.onMessageRead(message);
                        break;
                    case 3:
                        textView_amount.setText(cList.get("rosary_price"));
                        display_photo.setVisibility(View.GONE);
                        linearLayout10.setVisibility(View.GONE);
                        message_temp = textView_amount.getText().toString();


                        if(!message_temp.equals("")){
                            a = Integer.parseInt(message_temp);
                        }
                        a = a-temp;
                        message = Integer.toString(a);

                        messageReadListener.onMessageRead(message);
                        break;
                    case 4:
                        textView_amount.setText(cList.get("mass_price"));
                        display_photo.setVisibility(View.GONE);
                        linearLayout10.setVisibility(View.GONE);
                        message_temp = textView_amount.getText().toString();


                        if(!message_temp.equals("")){
                            a = Integer.parseInt(message_temp);
                        }
                        a = a-temp;
                        message = Integer.toString(a);

                        messageReadListener.onMessageRead(message);
                        break;
                    case 5:
                        textView_amount.setText(cList.get("prayer_price"));
                        display_photo.setVisibility(View.GONE);
                        linearLayout10.setVisibility(View.GONE);
                        message_temp = textView_amount.getText().toString();


                        if(!message_temp.equals("")){
                            a = Integer.parseInt(message_temp);
                        }
                        a = a-temp;
                        message = Integer.toString(a);

                        messageReadListener.onMessageRead(message);
                        break;
                    case 6:
                        textView_amount.setText(cList.get("marriageday_price"));
                        display_photo.setVisibility(View.GONE);
                        linearLayout10.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
                        message_temp = textView_amount.getText().toString();


                        if(!message_temp.equals("")){
                            a = Integer.parseInt(message_temp);
                        }
                        a = a-temp;
                        message = Integer.toString(a);

                        messageReadListener.onMessageRead(message);
                        break;
                }

//                String message = textView_amount.getText().toString();
//                messageReadListener.onMessageRead(message);
            }

            @Override
            public void onNothingSelected(AdapterView<?> parent) {

            }
        });
        return view;
    }


    private void showPictureDialog(){
        AlertDialog.Builder pictureDialog = new AlertDialog.Builder(getActivity());
        pictureDialog.setTitle("Select Action");
        String[] pictureDialogItems = {
                "Select photo from gallery",
                "Capture photo from camera" };
        pictureDialog.setItems(pictureDialogItems,
                new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                    @Override
                    public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
                        switch (which) {
                            case 0:
                                choosePhotoFromGallary();
                                break;
                            case 1:
                                takePhotoFromCamera();
                                break;
                        }
                    }
                });
        pictureDialog.show();
    }

    public void choosePhotoFromGallary() {
        Intent galleryIntent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_PICK,
                android.provider.MediaStore.Images.Media.EXTERNAL_CONTENT_URI);

        startActivityForResult(galleryIntent, GALLERY);
    }

    private void takePhotoFromCamera() {
        Intent intent = new Intent(android.provider.MediaStore.ACTION_IMAGE_CAPTURE);
        startActivityForResult(intent, CAMERA);
    }

    @Override
    public void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {

        super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);
        if (resultCode == getActivity().RESULT_CANCELED) {
            return;
        }
        if (requestCode == GALLERY) {
            if (data != null) {
                Uri contentURI = data.getData();
                Log.e(TAG, "contentURI : " + contentURI);
                try {
                    Bitmap bitmap = MediaStore.Images.Media.getBitmap(getActivity().getContentResolver(), contentURI);
                    String path = saveImage(bitmap);
                    Toast.makeText(getActivity(), "Image Saved!", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                    display_photo.setImageBitmap(bitmap);
                    Log.e(TAG, "PATH1" + path);
                    Log.e(TAG, "BITMAP " + bitmap);


                } catch (IOException e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                    Toast.makeText(getActivity(), "Failed!", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                }
            }

        } else if (requestCode == CAMERA) {
            Bitmap thumbnail = (Bitmap) data.getExtras().get("data");
            display_photo.setImageBitmap(thumbnail);
            path = saveImage(thumbnail);
            Log.e(TAG, "PATH2" + path);
            saveImage(thumbnail);
            Toast.makeText(getActivity(), "Image Saved!", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        }
    }

    public String saveImage(Bitmap myBitmap) {
        Log.e(TAG, "PATH3" + path);
        ByteArrayOutputStream bytes = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
        myBitmap.compress(Bitmap.CompressFormat.JPEG, 90, bytes);
        File wallpaperDirectory = new File(
                Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory() + IMAGE_DIRECTORY);
        Log.e(TAG, "wallpaperDirectory" + wallpaperDirectory);


        if (!wallpaperDirectory.exists()) {
            wallpaperDirectory.mkdirs();
        }

        try {
            File f = new File(wallpaperDirectory, Calendar.getInstance()
                    .getTimeInMillis() + ".jpg");
            f.createNewFile();
            FileOutputStream fo = new FileOutputStream(f);
            fo.write(bytes.toByteArray());
            MediaScannerConnection.scanFile(getActivity(),
                    new String[]{f.getPath()},
                    new String[]{"image/jpeg"}, null);
            fo.close();
            Log.d("TAG", "File Saved::--->" + f.getAbsolutePath());
            Log.e(TAG, "File Saved::--->" + f.getAbsolutePath());
            Log.e(TAG, "PATH4" + path);


            return f.getAbsolutePath();
        } catch (IOException e1) {
            e1.printStackTrace();
        }
        return "";
    }

    /*------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------*/

    public void getDetailsFromFragment() {



        service_value = textView_service_no.getText().toString();

        editText_dedicated_string = editText_dedicated.getText().toString();
        editText_intention_string = editText_intention.getText().toString();
        textView_telecast_date_string = textView_datePicker.getText().toString();
        textView_amount_string = textView_amount.getText().toString();

        service_spinner_string = spinner_services.getSelectedItem().toString();
        if(bitmap!=null){
            person_image_string = bitmap.toString();
        }


        Log.e(TAG, " SERVICE NO. : " + service_value + "  \n" + "SERVICES :" + service_spinner_string + " \n" + "DEDICATED TO : " + editText_dedicated_string + " \n" + " INTENTION : " +
                editText_intention_string + " \n" + " TELECASTE DATE : " + textView_telecast_date_string + " \n" + " AMOUNT : " + textView_amount_string + "\n" + "IMAGE : " + person_image_string);

        Log.e(TAG, "FINAL PAYMENT DETAILS: " + total_amount_string + " " + tax_amount_string + " " + final_total_amount_string);

        messageReadListener.onMessageRead(message);

    }


    public void changeCount(int a){
        c = a;
        textView_service_no.setText(valueOf(c));
    }




    @Override
    public void onAttach (Context context){
        super.onAttach(context);

        Activity activity = (Activity) context;

        try {


            messageReadListener = (OnMessageReadListener) activity;
        } catch (ClassCastException c) {
            throw new ClassCastException(activity.toString() + " must override onMessageReadListener...");
        }

    }
}

My activity is 

public class Services extends DashBoard implements Service_details.OnMessageReadListener{

@Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_services);
}

@OnClick(R.id.add_service)
    public void addService(){



        service_one_amount = Integer.parseInt(message4);
//        service_one_amount = message4;
        Log.e(TAG, "service_one_amount :  "+ service_one_amount);
//        service_one_amount = service_one_amount+ ;

        if(size<5){

            fragTag = "numericField" + numericFragmentCount;

            getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction().add(R.id.container_frame,Service_details.newInstance(a), fragTag).commit();
            ++a;
            ++numericFragmentCount;
            Log.e(TAG, "fragment size: "+ size);
        }else {
            Toast.makeText(this,"Maximum limit reached",Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        }


    }

    @OnClick(R.id.remove_service)
    public void removeService(){

        size= getSupportFragmentManager().getFragments().size();
        if(size>1) {

            --numericFragmentCount;

            fragTag = "numericField" + numericFragmentCount;
            fragment = getSupportFragmentManager().findFragmentById(R.id.container_frame);
            if (fragment != null) {
                getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction().remove(fragment).commit();
                --a;
            }
            Log.e(TAG, "fragment : " + fragment);
        }else {
            Toast.makeText(this,"Minimum limit reached",Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        }


    }

    @SuppressLint("SetTextI18n")
    @Override
    public void onMessageRead(String message) {

        try{

            String identity_frag = "numericField1";
            Fragment service_details1 = getSupportFragmentManager().findFragmentByTag("numericField1");
            Fragment service_details2 = getSupportFragmentManager().findFragmentByTag("numericField2");
            Fragment service_details3 = getSupportFragmentManager().findFragmentByTag("numericField3");
            Fragment service_details4 = getSupportFragmentManager().findFragmentByTag("numericField4");
            Fragment service_details5 = getSupportFragmentManager().findFragmentByTag("numericField5");

            Log.e(TAG,"before adding message4: "+message4);
            message1 = Integer.parseInt(message);
            service_details1 instanceof Service_details;
            Log.e(TAG,"before initial temp: "+ temp);
            if(!textView_amount_view.getText().toString().equals("0")){
                initial_amount= String.valueOf(message4);

            }else {
                initial_amount =textView_amount_view.getText().toString();
            }

            message3 = Integer.parseInt(initial_amount);
            message1= message3+message1-temp;
            temp = message1;
            Log.e(TAG,"after initial temp: "+ temp);
            message1 = message1+service_one_amount;
            long res = (long) Math.ceil((message1/ 100.0f) * 18);
            double res1 = ((message1/ 100f) * 18);

            Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "" + res1, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            int final_amount = (int) (message1 + res);
            message4 = Integer.toString(message1);
            Log.e(TAG,"after adding message4: "+message4);

            textView_amount_view.setText(currency_symbol+" "+ String.valueOf(message4));
            textView_tax_amount_view.setText(currency_symbol+" "+ String.valueOf(res)+ decimal_value);
            textView_total_amount_view.setText(currency_symbol+" "+ String.valueOf(final_amount)+ decimal_value);
            Log.e(TAG,"total amount: "+message4);
            Log.e(TAG,"tax amount: "+res);
            Log.e(TAG,"amount after tax: "+final_amount);


        }catch (NumberFormatException e){
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }




}
```

if u find question is hard please upvote to reach more people..
Thanks in advance..

Comment: create one interface call callback interface and when spinner value change use that callback. it will notify your main fragment.

Comment: i can get changed item but unable to identify which fragment have changed